# How can I check if the Property value of type Enum in a Custom Control has changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, controls, custom-controls

I created a custom control class which inherits from `Button`.
The reason I did that is I need to create the same Button and I don't want to do everything every single time.
Also, I want a DropDown list selector for the properties that I add, accessible from the Properties Grid in the Form Designer.

For example, I want three different colors and no other, so I want a DropDown selector on for this new Property. I used an Enum for that and it worked, but the problem is when I select for example `Red`, it doesn't change the color. My code is:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public NormalColor CLR { get; set; }

    public enum NormalColor
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Yellow
    }

    public CustomButton()
    {
        if (CLR == NormalColor.Blue)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (CLR == NormalColor.Red)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (CLR == NormalColor.Yellow)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(18, 18, 18);
        }

        ForeColor = Color.White;
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        Size = new Size(100, 100);
        MouseEnter += CustomButton_MouseEnter;
        MouseLeave += CustomButton_MouseLeave;
        MouseClick += CustomButton_MouseClick;
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor is called FIRST - before any other code ...So perhaps you need to move your CLR if statements into another method and call it when you change CLR value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a control Constructor you can define its base (default) properties, not its behaviour or how a Control responds to user settings.

Your Public Properties are delegated to this task.

> Note that I've inserted the `InitializeComponent()` procedure, so the
> Control can be dropped in a container from the ToolBox.

If you want to hide your Control's `BackColor` Property in the Property window at Design Time, override the property and hide it with:

`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]`

You could change your `CustomButton` this way:
(With the current settings, when you drop your control on a Form from the Toolbox, it will be drawn with a red `BackColor` and a white `ForeColor`).

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    private NormalColor CurrentColorSelection = 0;
    public NormalColor CLR
    {
        get { return CurrentColorSelection; }
        set { SetBackColor(value); }
    }

    public enum NormalColor
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Yellow
    }

    public CustomButton() => InitializeComponent();

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        SetBackColor(CurrentColorSelection);
        this.ForeColor = Color.White;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        this.MouseEnter += this.CustomButton_MouseEnter;
        this.MouseLeave += this.CustomButton_MouseLeave;
        this.MouseClick += this.CustomButton_MouseClick;
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }

    private void SetBackColor(NormalColor value)
    {
        this.CurrentColorSelection = value;
        this.BackColor = Color.FromName(value.ToString());
    }
    
   //(...)
   //Event Handlers
}
```

Comment: @HeroOfSkies  Glad it helped :) Note that, to change the background color, I've used `this.BackColor = Color.FromName(value.ToString())`. This means that the color list in your `NormalColor` enumerator must be a [KnownColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) name, otherwise that method will fail. If you plan on using *special* names (not included in the `KnownColor` list), modify that method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the button class `constructor` is executed first, so in your code flow make sure that CLR is set while instantiating

**Do following**

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
 public NormalColor CLR 
 { 
    get; 
    private set; 
 }

 public enum NormalColor
 {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Yellow
 }
#region Constructor

public CustomButton(NormalColor backgroundColor)
{
    CLR = backgroundColor;
    if (CLR == NormalColor.Blue)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
   /*Your other code*/
 }
}
```